# Keep value if repeated within a 24 hour time period

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to figure out the best approach for my problem. Considering the following dataset:

[image]

I am looking for a way to iteratively loop through the panda table, and flag any 'Event' which is not repeated within 24 hours of each 'Event' 'Date. As denoted by the 'Keep' column in this example.

In this example 'Walk' and 'Hop' are both denoted with a  '0' as they do not have a repeating 'Event' within the 24 hour timeframe.

My initial thought was loop through each row, extract rows based on the 'Date' plus 24 hours and do a check for the first occurrence of 'Event' but this seems very resource intensive and curious if there is an easier way.

Comment: Please paste your dataframe in a reproducible format (eg df.to_dict() ) so that we can experiment

Comment: Agree, with @IoaTzimas , not sure how this question got 3 upvotes

Comment: How come for example the last "Walk" is 1? There is no occurrence of "Walk" after it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an interesting question. Unless I misunderstood something, I suspect your example to be incorrect. For instance, each last occurrence of an event should be 0 as it is by definition the last and thus not repeated afterwards.

That said, this is quite easy. You can sort by date, group by event and calculate the time difference between consecutive rows. Finally, apply a threshold (here < 1 day).

Assuming this input:

```
  event                date
0     R 2000-01-01 11:40:00
1     R 2000-01-01 12:40:00
2     W 2000-01-01 12:40:00
3     S 2000-01-03 11:00:00
4     H 2000-01-03 12:00:00
5     S 2000-01-03 19:00:00
6     H 2000-01-04 13:00:00
7     W 2000-01-03 09:00:00
8     W 2000-01-03 10:00:00
9     H 2000-01-04 14:00:00
```

```py
df = df.sort_values(by='date')
df['keep'] = (df.groupby('event')['date']
               .apply(lambda d: d.diff().shift(-1) < pd.Timedelta('1D'))
               .astype(int)
             )
```

output:

```
  event                date  keep
0     R 2000-01-01 11:40:00     1
1     R 2000-01-01 12:40:00     0
2     W 2000-01-01 12:40:00     0
3     S 2000-01-03 11:00:00     1
4     H 2000-01-03 12:00:00     0
5     S 2000-01-03 19:00:00     0
6     H 2000-01-04 13:00:00     1
7     W 2000-01-03 09:00:00     1
8     W 2000-01-03 10:00:00     0
9     H 2000-01-04 14:00:00     0
```